# How to filter value in list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

we have beans values in ArrayList. how do we filter below is sample of ArrayList  contains.

```
   List =  [number ABCEFG , EndDATE  2020-03-01],[number ABCEFG , EndDATE 2020-04-01],[number KLMNOP , EndDATE 2020-04-01]
```

Condition to filter get recent endate for number(ABCEFG) from arraylist using java 1.5 to 1.8

After filter is done Output should be

```
 List =[number ABCEFG ,EndDATE 2020-04-01],[number KLMNOP ,EndDATE 2020-04-01]
```

No idea how to start so did not try any code

Comment: _using java 1.5 to 1.8_ Do you want a solution that works in Java 1.5 and another solution that works in Java 1.8 ? Also, maybe you can [edit] your question and post some more details of what exactly these _beans values_ are? I can guess but I think it's better that you post the details.

Comment: if we have easy solution  in 1.5 it is ok but in java 1.8  also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use java 1.8 streaming API. In streaming API you can use filter in which you can write your own condition logic on enddate and collect the collection to return.

```
List<Object> collect = list.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getEndDate() /*add your condition here*/)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to sort list based on end date you can use sort

```
   stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDate(Object::getEndDate))
```

P.S.: I have not provided exact code, objective is user should get hint to solve problem by themselve.